# What to pass to class with IConfiguration Constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a class that contains a method that uses some database connection strings and instead of hard coding them, I want to pull them from my `appsettings.json` file. So, following others who have [done similar things](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configuration-in-asp-net-core/), I created a constructor with an `IConfiguration` parameter. I am attempting to use the `SearchOfficer` method in a Blazor Page's base class, to do so I tried to make a new instance of Search but couldn't figure out: what should I pass to the constructor?

The Class with the Method:

```cs
public class Searches
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Searches(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }
           
    public async Task<List<NameScore>> SearchOfficer(string Input)
    {            
        //processy stuff

        //Querying stuff
        DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
        string sql = "SELECT IdOfficer, Name FROM officers";
        List<FirstLoadOfficer> Names = await data.LoadData<FirstLoadOfficer, dynamic>
                                       (sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("DataDB"));
      
        //Sorting and Comparing stuff
        return SortedNames;        
    }
}
```

How I am attempting to use it:

```cs
 Searches searches = new Searches(/*what should I put here?*/);
 SimilarPeople = await searches.SearchOfficer("Input Name");
```

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection configured at startup?

Comment: Avoid injecting `IConfiguration` (code smell). Consider explicitly injecting what is actually needed in the target class.

Comment: You are also not following what was shown in the linked article. Use the Options pattern if possible

Comment: "I'm creating a new instance of this class in another file" - this is very confusing statement combined with "asp.net-core" tag. Please [edit] question to make sure tags/code matches each other... Also add some clarification why straight forward "use an instance of a class that implements that interface" is not an answer in *your case* would help too (indeed it should not be the case if you use DI as expected in asp.net-core, but you aren't so...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm not very familiar with Dependency Injection. @Nkosi, I'm not quite sure how I could inject only what is needed, could you explain further please? AlexeiLevenkov, I don't see how those tags are conflicting, nor do I understand DI well enough to apply it properly to my situation, hence the question

Comment: @Bubinga where is the attempted code shown going to be invoked? In a Controller?

Comment: It is in a Blazor Component/Page's Base class, I'll clarify that in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid injecting `IConfiguration` (code smell). Consider explicitly injecting what is actually needed in the target class.

You are not following what was shown in the linked article.

It suggests creating a model to hold the information needed, which in this case could look something like

```
public class ConnectionStrings
    public string DataDB { get; set; }  
}
```

Configure the model in startup

```
//...

services.AddOptions();  
  
//Configure Option using Extensions method  
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")); 

//...
```

And refactor the target class to depend on the model via dependency injection and the options pattern

```
public class Searches : ISearches {
    private readonly ConnectionStrings connectionStrings;

    public Searches(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> options) {
        connectionStrings = options.Value;
    }
           
    public async Task<List<NameScore>> SearchOfficer(string Input) {
        //processy stuff

        //Querying stuff
        DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
        string sql = "SELECT IdOfficer, Name FROM officers";
        List<FirstLoadOfficer> Names = await data
            .LoadData<FirstLoadOfficer, dynamic>(sql, new { }, connectionStrings.DataDB);
      
        //Sorting and Comparing stuff
        return SortedNames;        
    }
}
```

Ideally the target class should be backed by an abstraction (interface) and registered

```
//...

services.AddScoped<ISearches, Searches>();

//...
```

With that, it is a matter of injecting the abstraction where it is needed

```
@inject ISearches searches

...

@code {
    SimilarPeople = await searches.SearchOfficer("Input Name");
}
```

Reference [ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection)